# Create a back button for form

Tags: php, html

I've created a 2 step form with the following code:

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/contact-us/">
    <? if (!$_POST['step']) { ?>
    <h1>Step 1 of 2</h1><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="1" />               
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="Title*" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>        
    <button class="continue-button" type="submit" name="submit">Continue</button>
    <? } else if ($_POST['step'] == 1) {
        foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
        if ($name <> "step") { echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\" />"; }
    } ?>
    <h1>Step 2 of 2</h1><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="2" />
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Name*" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>        
    <button class="continue-button" type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
    <? } else if ($_POST['step'] == 2) { //do stuff 
        echo "Do stuff here";
    } ?>
</form>
```

How can I add a back button on step 2? There will be several steps added not just 2 so the user needs to be able to move forward and back through the steps whilst keeping what they've filled in.

Comment: I have deleted my answer. Please update your question to show you want more than 2 steps and to be able to navigate through them. I'll start on a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/contact-us/">
    <? if (!$_POST['step']) { ?>
    <h1>Step 1 of 2</h1><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="1" />               
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?= $_REQUEST["title"]?>"  placeholder="Title*" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>        
    <button class="continue-button" type="submit" name="submit">Continue</button>
    <? } else if ($_POST['step'] == 1) {
        $field  ="";
        foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
        if ($name <> "step") { echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\" />";  $field .= $name."=".$value."&";}
    } ?>
    <div><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/contact-us/?<?= $field ?>" >Back</a></div>
    <h1>Step 2 of 2</h1><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="2" />
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Name*" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>        
    <button class="continue-button" type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
    <? } else if ($_POST['step'] == 2) { //do stuff 
        echo "Do stuff here";
    } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. (Also didn't know you could do `placeholder="text"`).

Answer (score 1):

First add it on top of your page

```
// keep the data
$_SESSION['data'] = $_POST;
$_SESSION['step'] = $_REQUEST['step'];
```

Also replace the `if` statement to something like this:

```
if ($_REQUEST['step'] == 1) {
    // continue
```

Write dynamic values on your form

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" 
value="<?php echo $_SESSION['data']['title']; ?>" />
```

Use a `link` for `Back` and `Next`:

```
<a href="/?step=<?php echo $_SESSION['step'] - 1; ?>">Back</a>

<a href="/?step=<?php echo $_SESSION['step'] + 1; ?>">Next</a>
```

I guess it would works for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

To navigate back and forwards you will want to pass the data from the previous form back to it again so you would need to store the value of each form somewhere. Your best bet would be to create a `session` and store each form info in a session variable. Then when you load each form you should check to see if the data is already stored in a session.

Then you could add a jquery button to change the value of the step and submit the form.
To do this you would need to the 'step' hidden input an id like 'step'

```
<input type="hidden" name="step" id="step" value="2" />
```

and then add a button like

```
<button class="back-button" type="submit" name="back" onclick="$('#step').val('1');">Back</button>
```

This would change the value of the step input and then submit the form taking you back to the previous form.

You would need to have another hidden input to tell the form where it came from so it would know whether to look at the session data (is you're going backwards) or the POST data (if youre going forwards).

Comment: Sorry should've been more clear in the question... there's going to be more than 2 steps, so they need to be able to move forward and back through the form.